# MBProgressHUD Changing Animation Type

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

So I am using the `MBProgressHUD` for a loading view.  I am able to get the `MBProgressHUDModeIndeterminate` to work and show it loading.  However whenever I try to use any other type such as MBProgressHUDModeDeterminate or the other ones, I do not see these animated.  All I see is a solid white circle that doesn't move.  In my code, I am calling the method as such:

```
HUD = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];
```

so I was wondering if anyone could help me out.

Comment: Did you add its delegate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the method `[HUD setProgress:float]` where float is a float value between 0 and 1 to set the progress value of a `MBProgressHUDModeDeterminate` type HUD.

What is it exactly you are trying to monitor the progress of?  Perhaps a more specific question and code example will get you a more specific and helpful answer

Answer (score 0):

Step 1 : Add MBProgressHUD.h & MBProgressHUD.m files in our

Step 2

```
#import "MBProgressHUD.h"
```

Step 3 :

```
MBProgressHUD *hud = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];
hud.mode = MBProgressHUDModeInDeterminate;
hud.labelText = @"Uploading";
[hud show:YES];
```

Step 4 :

```
[hud hide:YES];
```

More Details [here](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-save-data-parse-cloud-tutorial/)